React Page getting blank after changing css
I was stylishing the navbar of my react page, when after changing the color of the selected button of the navbar, the page suddently got blank, and I don't know the reason, I already tried to ctrl+z the code, but that doesn't work
The .jsx file
//Esse arquivo contém a página dashboard que é acessada ao usuário fazer login

import {useContext} from "react";
import {UserContext} from "../../context/userContext"
import '../dashboard.css'
import 'boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css';
import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css';
import '../menu.js'

export default function Dashboard() {
    useContext(UserContext)
  return (
    <div>
    <nav className="menu-lateral">
            <h1>APPROVE</h1>
            <ul>
                <li className="item-menu ativo">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span className="icon"><i className="bi bi-book"></i></span>
                        <span className="txt-link">ESTUDAR</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li className="item-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span className="icon-img"><img src="medalhabranca.png" alt="" /></span>
                        <span className="txt-link">RANKING</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li className="item-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span className="icon"><i className="bi bi-shop"></i></span>
                        <span className="txt-link">LOJA</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li className="item-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span className="icon"><i className="bi bi-person-fill"></i></span>
                        <span className="txt-link">PERFIL</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li className="item-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span className="icon"><i className="bi bi-gear-fill"></i></span>
                        <span className="txt-link">AJUSTES</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <script src="../menu.js"></script>
    

      
    </div>
  )
}
 

the .css file
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

body {
    height: 900vh;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'rakkas', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
   
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.icon-img {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

nav.menu-lateral {
    width: 300px; /* Defina a largura fixa do menu */
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #02AFED;
    padding: 40px 0px 40px 1%;
    box-shadow: 3px 0 0 #4169E1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
}

ul {
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li.item-menu {
    transition: .2s;
}

ul li.ativo {
    background-color: #4169E1;
}

ul li.item-menu:hover {
    background: #4169E1;
}

ul li.item-menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 4%;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

ul li.item-menu a .txt-link {
    margin-left: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
}

ul li.item-menu a .icon > i {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

How the page gets
I don't know the reason, I really just changed the "ul li.ativo" color and then suddently doesn't work anymore

Try import '../dashboard.css' move this to the bottom, at the end of imports.
